# Solving system of differential equations using loops

Tags: differential-equations

I have $F$ system of differential equations. Out of those $F$ equations except for first and last I have general form for the remaining equations (say $ dP_{i}/dt)$.
Let $dP_0/dt,dP_F/dt$  denotes the 1st and last equations respectively. 
Now I would like to solve them for varies values of $F$.
i,e, If F=3, I will have only three equations in which $dP_1/dt$ I will get from general form $dP_i/dt$ by putting i=1, 
Similarly for other values F's. 
Can some one help me out solve this for different values of $F$ using for, while loops.

**Edit:** I tried in following way.

```
node[0,F] = p[0]'[t] == first eqn ;
node[i,F] = p[i]'[t] == i^{th} eqn ;
node[F,F] = p[F]'[t] == F^{th}eqn;
```

for example for F=4

```
system = Table[node[i, F], {i, 1, 3}, {F, 4, 4}]
```

(I am missing first and last equation in table, I don't know how include them)
Then I am thinking to use NDSolve[system] but I don't know exact syntax for this. Each of equation have different initial conditions also.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are unable to understand or need more information please let me know.

Comment: If you would add some *Mathematica* code (e.g. for your equations and for what you have tried for the loops) it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: @Karsten 7 I have added some extra details, Thanks

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to  include the **Mathematica code** you are working on. Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers. See the [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for proper formatting.

Comment: I edited your code this time. Please learn how to format your post by following the links provided by @rhermans above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on all the details of your problem, but here is a general setup:

```
system = Table[node[i, F], {i, 0, F}]; (* equations *)
initialvalues = {p0, p1, ... (* fill in as appropriate with actual numbers *)};
initialcondition = Table[p[i][0] == initialvalues[[i+1]], {i, 0, F}];
funcs = Table[p[i], {i, 0, F}];  (* functions to solve for *)
sol =
 NDSolve[{system, initialcondition}, funcs, {t, t1, t2}] (* return solution for t1 <= t <= t2 *)
```

The initial values and the time interval were not specified in the question, so I leave them for you to fill in.  The list `initialvalues` needs to contain `F + 1` numbers.  Since *Mathematica* indices always begin with `1`, the index `i` will be one off the [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/<code>Part</code>.html) number.  Also, the times `t1` and `t2` need to be definite numbers.

`DSolve` might be used in place of `NDSolve` if the system can be integrated symbolically.  In that case the last argument is usually just `t`.